# ruby language - merge an array into another by finding same element

Tags: ruby

```
A = [
  { :id => 1, :name => 'good', :link => nil },
  { :id => 2, :name => 'bad', :link => nil } 
]

B = [
  { :id => 3, :name => 'good' },
  { :id => 4, :name => 'good' }, 
  { :id => 5, :name => 'bad' } 
]
```

I need to merge array B into A so that `:link` in array A includes the entry in array B if `:name` is the same value in each array.

For example, after processing array A should be:

```
A = [
  { :id => 1, :name => 'good', :link => [{ :id => 3, :name => 'good' }, { :id => 4, :name => 'good' }] },
  { :id => 2, :name => 'bad', :link => [{ :id => 5, :name => 'bad' }] }
]
```

thanks.

Comment: is the expected A correct? bad should have link (id=5).

Comment: hint: don't upload, create new objects (so merge instead of update).

Comment: @tokland: sorry, you are right.   bad should have link (id=5). thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short version;

```
a.each { | item | item[:link] = b.find_all { | x | x[:name] == item[:name] } }
```

Demo [here](http://codepad.org/WN3DVtJb).

Comment: of course, this only updates existing values in a, it doesn't create new keys from b if they exist in ba but not a.

Answer (score 1):

In ruby the constants begin with an uppercase letter, so you should use lowercase letter:
A => a, B => b

```
a.each do |ha|
  b.each do |hb|
    if ha[:name] == hb[:name]
      ha[:link] |= []
      ha[:link] << hb
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Functional approach:

```
B_grouped = B.group_by { |h| h[:name]  }
A2 = A.map { |h| h.merge(:link => B_grouped[h[:name]]) }
#=> [{:link=>[{:name=>"good", :id=>3}, {:name=>"good", :id=>4}], :name=>"good", :id=>1},
#    {:link=>[{:name=>"bad", :id=>5}], :name=>"bad", :id=>2}]
```